# Linux kernel 2.6 on ARM

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded, arm, hardware

I have compiled and installed the 2.6 kernel on an ARM board. I am using the ARM [mini2440](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440) board.

I would like to know if there is already a way to access the General Purpose I/O port pins?

Or will I have to do `ioctl()` and access them directly from the memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `sysfs` control files in `/sys/class/gpio`.  The following links will hopefully be useful to helping you get started:

[http://www.avrfreaks.net/wiki/index.php/Documentation:Linux/GPIO](http://www.avrfreaks.net/wiki/index.php/Documentation%3aLinux/GPIO)

Have seen reports of this article on the Beagle Board also working with the mini2440:
http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2009/02/blinking_leds_with_the_beagle_board.html

In your Linux kernel documentation, look at [Documentation/gpio.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/gpio.txt;hb=HEAD) too.